# Access Java class method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, scriptlet

I have a jsp page like below:

```
<@page import ="com.somepackage.ClientData"%>
<html>
    <body onload = "callMyFunc()">
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function callMyFunc(){
                var clientName = ClientData.getClientName();
                document.getElementById('clientname').value = clientName;
            }
        </script>
        <form>
            <input type ="text" id="clientname">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to set the clientname using above approach.
How do I access my .java class method in javascript function? Or is there any other way to do?
Please help.

Comment: you can't, because java runs on the server and javascript in the browser - two completely separate environments

Comment: you need to map a url to the method and use ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use java method into javascript function as below.
Need to import class as you already done.

In java script function you have to use

```
var clientName = '<%= ClientData.getClientName() %>';
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried this but its not working in javascript.
Exception occurred while processing jsp page.

Comment: can you post error stack. because i am able to use this